# @ManyToMany annotation spring boot JPA with extra column and composite key ,Error inserting

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, many-to-many

I'm using spring boot 2.2.5 with  Jpa and JDK 11 and for my database i'm using oracle 19c.
I have a ManyToMany relationship between my entities User and Group.
In my oracle database i have a associated (USER_GROUP) table with composite key (user_ID,group_ID).
USER_ID and GROUP_ID are automaticaly generated in the database.
I want when i insert a user in table USER JPA also insert in associated table USER_GROUP.
But it return  always cannot insert null in USER_ID,and this user id  i don't have access because it generated automatily in database.

MyClass UserGroup:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_GROUP", schema = "TEST", catalog = "")
public class UserGroup  {

    private GroupUserPK  groupUserPK;
    private User user;
    private Group group;


    @EmbeddedId
    public GroupUserPK getGroupUserPK() {
        return groupUserPK;
    }
    public void setGroupUserPK(GroupUserPK groupUserPK) {
        this.groupUserPK = groupUserPK;
    }


    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_USER_ID")
    @MapsId("fkUserId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_GROUP_ID")
    @MapsId("fkGroupId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }
}
```

UserGroupPK

```
@Embeddable
public class GroupUserPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long fkUserId;
    private long fkGroupId;


    @Column(name = "FK_USER_ID")
    @Id
    public long getFkUserId() {
        return fkUserId;
    }

    public void setFkUserId(long fkUserId) {
        this.fkUserId = fkUserId;
    }
    @Column(name = "FK_GROUP_ID")
    @Id
    public long getFkGroupId() {
        return fkGroupId;
    }
    public void setFkGroupId(long fkGroupId) {
        this.fkGroupId = fkGroupId;
    }

}
```

MyClass Group:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP", schema = "TEST", catalog = "")
public class Group {
    private long groupId;
    private String nom;
    private Collection<UserGroup> userGroup;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    public long getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(long groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DESIGN")
    public String getDesign() {
        return design;
    }

    public void setDesign(String design) {
        this.design = design;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public Collection<UserGroup> getUserGroup() {
        return userGroup;
    }

    public void setUserGroup(Collection<UserGroup> userGroup) {
        this.userGroup = userGroup;
    }

}
```

MyClass User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", schema = "TEST", catalog = "")
public class User {
    private long userId;
    private String nom;
    private Collection<UserGroup> userGroup;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DESIGN")
    public String getDesign() {
        return design;
    }

    public void setDesign(String design) {
        this.design = design;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public Collection<UserGroup> getUserGroup() {
        return userGroup;
    }

    public void setUserGroup(Collection<UserGroup> userGroup) {
        this.userGroup = userGroup;
    }

}
```

Any help please.

Comment: What is the error? Can you provide stacktrace?

Comment: i don't have an error it's doesn't insert into assoction table "GROUP_USER"

Comment: Table should be USER_GROUP right?. Provide the test method used to save then

Comment: Okay thank you it's work for me now

Comment: Answer your own question it may help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit

I solved this problem by adding "addGroup" method in my entity User.

My entity user updated as,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", schema = "TEST", catalog = "")
public class User {
    private long userId;
    private String nom;
    private Collection<UserGroup> userGroups;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DESIGN")
    public String getDesign() {
        return design;
    }

    public void setDesign(String design) {
        this.design = design;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public Collection<UserGroup> getUserGroups() {
        return userGroups;
    }

    public void setUserGroup(Collection<UserGroup> userGroups) {
        this.userGroups = userGroups;
    }

    public void addGroup(Group group) {
        UserGroup  userGroup = new UserGroup(this, group);
        userGroups.add(userGroup);
        group.getUserGroups().add(userGroup);
    }


}
```

After that we called this method in UserService.